# SQL - Table Design - DateCreated and DateUpdated columns

Tags: sql, timestamp, insert-update

For my application there are several entity classes, User, Customer, Post, and so on

I'm about to design the database and I want to store the date when the entities were created and updated. This is where it gets tricky. Sure one option is to add created_timestamp and update_timestamp columns for each of the entity tables but that isn't that redudant?

Another possibility could be to create a log table that stores this information, and it could be made to contain keep track of updates for **any** entity.

Any thoughts? I'm leaning on implementing the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The single-log-table-for-all-tables approach has two main problems that I can think of:

1. The design of the log table will (probably) constrain the design of all the other tables.  Most likely the log table would have one column named TableName and then another column named PKValue (which would store the primary key value for the record you're logging).  If some of your tables have compound primary keys (i.e. more than one column), then the design of your log table would have to account for this (probably by having columns like PKValue1, PKValue2 etc.).
2. If this is a web application of some sort, then the user identity that would be available from a trigger would be the application's account, instead of the ID of the web app user (which is most likely what you really want to store in your CreatedBy field).  This would only help you distinguish between records created by your web app code and records created otherwise.

CreatedDate and ModifiedDate columns aren't redundant just because they're defined in each table.  I would stick with that approach and put insert and update triggers on each table to populate those columns.  If I also needed to record the end-user who made the change, I would skip the triggers and populate the timestamp and user fields from my application code.

Answer (score 5):

I do the latter, with a "log" or "events" table.  In my experience, the "updated" timestamp becomes frustrating pretty quick, because a lot of the time you find yourself in a fix where you want not just the very latest update time.

Answer (score 0):

How often will you need to include the created/updated timestamps in your presentation layer? If the answer is anything more than "once in a great great while", I think you would be better served by having those columns in each table.

Answer (score 0):

On a project I worked on a couple of years ago, we implemented triggers which updated what we called an audit table (it stored basic information about the changes being made, one audit table per table).  This included modified date (and last modified).

They were only applied to key tables (not joins or reference data tables).

This removed a lot of the normal frustration of having to account for LastCreated & LastModified fields, but introduced the annoyance of keeping the triggers up to date.

In the end the trigger/audit table design worked well and all we had to remember was to remove and reapply the triggers before ETL(!).

Answer (score 0):

It's for a web based CMS I work on. The creation and last updated dates will be displayed on most pages and there will be lists for the last created (and updated) pages. The admin interface will also use this information.